# Angular momentum singlet states for arbitrary representations

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory

Suppose we have two-particle states

$$ |0\rangle^{(j)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big(|+m,-m\rangle - |-m,+m\rangle \big) $$

based on one-particle states in the SU(2) $j$-representation, where I use the notation

$$ |+m,-m\rangle = |j,+m\rangle \otimes |j,-m\rangle $$

with arbitrary $j = 1/2, 1, 3/2, \ldots$ and $m \le j$.

A rotation $ R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) $ acts as *)

$$ R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \, |+m,-m\rangle = R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \, |j,+m\rangle \otimes R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \,|j,-m\rangle $$

For singlet states the rotations reduce to the identity.

Is there a simple way to *see* that for the above mentioned states $|0\rangle^{(j)}$ without going through the calculation of matrix elements, i.e. Wigner D-functions for each representation j?

*)

$$ R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = e^{-i\alpha J_z} e^{-i\beta J_y} e^{-i\gamma J_z} $$

$$ J_i = J_i^{(1)} \otimes 1^{(2)} + 1^{(1)} \otimes J_i^{(2)} $$

$$ \implies \; R(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = R^{(1)}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \otimes R^{(2)}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation matrices are but exponentials of linear combinations of generators *J*, both at the tensor factor level and the coproduct level. So if you see that all three coproduct generators in the [ladder decomplexified basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_operator#Angular_momentum), $J_z,J_{\pm}$, annihilate your state, for any *j*, you have seen that their exponential amounts to the identity for that state.
Conversely, if some (combinations of) generators do not annihilate your state, then there is a departure from the identity, in general, e.g. for a small angle, and your state is not a singlet.

Now, indeed, for your state,
$$
J_z  \Big( |+m,-m\rangle - |-m,+m\rangle \Big )\\ =\Big((m-m) |+m,-m\rangle -(-m+m) |-m,+m\rangle \Big ) =0.
$$

However, examine the action of $J_+$ on it, but take *j*=2, *m*=1, for simplicity.
$$
J_+  \Big( |1,-1\rangle - |-1,1\rangle \Big )\\ =
\Big( 2 |2,-1\rangle +
\sqrt{ 6 } |1, 0\rangle  
- \sqrt{ 6  } | 0, 1\rangle - 2 | -1, 2\rangle \Big )\neq 0.
$$
This is not a singlet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, done; I thought about it, and it's clear that one has to use the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients to couple all $|j,m_1\rangle, |j,m_2\rangle$ to $|JM\rangle = |00\rangle$